# I would like to modify the npm library html, is this possible?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I would like to modify the npm library html, is this possible?

```
>>> package.json
"dependencies": {
    "vuetify-confirm": "^2.0.6",
}
```

target : vuetify-confirm
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-confirm?activeTab=readme)

```
>>> vuetify-confirm.js
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory(require('vuetify/lib')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['vuetify/lib'], factory) :
    (global.vuetifyConfirm = factory(global.Vue.options.components));
}(this, (function (lib) { 'use strict';

var Confirm = { render: function () {
    var _vm = this;var _h = _vm.$createElement;var _c = _vm._self._c || _h;return _c('v-dialog', { attrs: { "eager": "", "value": "true", "max-width": _vm.width, "persistent": _vm.persistent }, on: { "input": _vm.change, "keydown": function ($event) {
          if (!('button' in $event) && _vm._k($event.keyCode, "esc", 27, $event.key, "Escape")) {
            return null;
          }_vm.choose(false);
        } } }, [_c('v-card', { attrs: { "tile": "" } }, [Boolean(_vm.title) ? _c('v-toolbar', { attrs: { "dark": "", "color": _vm.color, "dense": "", "flat": "" } }, [Boolean(_vm.icon) ? _c('v-icon', { attrs: { "left": "" } }, [_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.icon))]) : _vm._e(), _vm._v(" "), _c('v-toolbar-title', { staticClass: "white--text", domProps: { "textContent": _vm._s(_vm.title) } })], 1) : _vm._e(), _vm._v(" "), _c('v-card-text', { staticClass: "body-1 text-body-1 py-3", domProps: { "innerHTML": _vm._s(_vm.message) } }), _vm._v(" "), _c('v-card-actions', [_c('v-spacer'), _vm._v(" "), Boolean(_vm.buttonFalseText) ? _c('v-btn', { attrs: { "color": _vm.buttonFalseColor, "text": _vm.buttonFalseFlat }, on: { "click": function ($event) {
          _vm.choose(false);
        } } }, [_vm._v(" " + _vm._s(_vm.buttonFalseText) + " ")]) : _vm._e(), _vm._v(" "), Boolean(_vm.buttonTrueText) ? _c('v-btn', { attrs: { "color": _vm.buttonTrueColor, "text": _vm.buttonTrueFlat }, on: { "click": function ($event) {
          _vm.choose(true);
        } } }, [_vm._v(" " + _vm._s(_vm.buttonTrueText) + " ")]) : _vm._e()], 1)], 1)], 1);
  }, staticRenderFns: [],
  components: {
    VCard: lib.VCard,
    VCardActions: lib.VCardActions,
    VCardText: lib.VCardText,
    VDialog: lib.VDialog,
    VIcon: lib.VIcon,
    VToolbar: lib.VToolbar,
    VToolbarTitle: lib.VToolbarTitle,
    VSpacer: lib.VSpacer,
    VBtn: lib.VBtn
  },
... blah blah
```

I think the html is structured like this

Is there a way to override or modify this?

I want to change the design

For example, changing the color of the button with the CSS I have.

Comment: It looks like in their docs they give you options to modify some of the colors.  You can also just target the html with normal css selectors.  If you really need customization, this is just a wrapper over the normal [vuetify dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/) so you could use that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.

but you can fork the [source](https://github.com/yariksav/vuetify-confirm) and add it as a workspace in your local project.

```json
 "workspaces" : [ "path/to/vuetify-confirm" ]
 "dependencies": {
    "vuetify-confirm": "file:path/to/vuetify-confirm",
 }
```

Then you can modify and rebuild the package to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

For short:

> You CANNOT do that

For long:

- All packages in any kinds of languages/frameworks/eco-systems are supposed to be downloaded and used, not DIRECTLY modified.
- You can modify the one you downloaded but that for testing purpose. Eventually, once you go to deploy mode, if you want your modification to be available, you need to MANUALY copy everything you changed into the production environment.

So to have your own customize version

- Fork the code to your Github (or your favorite SVC)
- Make modify and commit
- Use npm to install directly from your SVC

Here is npm doc for installing from git
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install